# How do I solve SqlNullValueException?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to find an entity but I get a SqlNullValueException when entity framework is trying to get the value of a field that's Null.

I checked in the database and all the not nullable fields are filled. The only fields that have a NULL value are the ones that are allowed to have it.

In other answers I found that I should remove required attribute from the class properties or remove the IsRequired method from modelbuilder definition, however I autogenerated these and they never had a required definition.

My app runs on .NET Core 3.1 and my EntityFrameworkCore is version 2.2.4. Even though it builds succesfully could this cause the issue? **Update** All versions are 3.1 now.

If not, what else can cause it?

To find the entity I'm using the following method:

```
public static CodeLists FindCodeListById(Guid id)
{
    using (var context = new classificatielocalContext())
    {
        return context.CodeLists.Find(id);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException
>
> HResult=0x80131931
>
> Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>
> Source=System.Data.Common
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.get_Value()`
>
> at `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()`
>
> at `System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()`
>
> at `System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)`
>
> at `System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.b__0(QueryContext qc)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)`
>
> at `System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)`
>
> at `dal.Views.FindCodeListById(Guid id)` in ...
>
> at `services.CodeListService.GetCodeList(Guid id)`  in ...
>
> at `api.Controllers.CodeListController.Get(Guid id)` in ...
>
> at `Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)`
>
> at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)`
>
> at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()`

I am using `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` to define my entities and no where have I defined that my columns are required.

Here is my modelbuilder definition:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CodeLists>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
        .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

    entity.ToTable("code_lists");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnName("id")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");

    entity.Property(e => e.ClassificationId).HasColumnName("classification_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.DescriptionId).HasColumnName("description_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.NameId).HasColumnName("name_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.OwnerId).HasColumnName("owner_id");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Classification)
        .WithMany(p => p.CodeLists)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClassificationId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK__code_list__class__5FB337D6");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Description)
        .WithMany(p => p.CodeListsDescription)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DescriptionId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK__code_list__descr__60A75C0F");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Name)
        .WithMany(p => p.CodeListsName)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.NameId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK__code_list__name___619B8048");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Owner)
        .WithMany(p => p.CodeLists)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.OwnerId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK__code_list__owner__628FA481");
});
```

And here is my sql definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[code_lists]
(
    [id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [classification_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES classifications(id), -- TODO: Should be set to NOT NULL
    [description_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES translations(id),
    [name_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES translations(id),
    [owner_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(id), -- TODO: Should be set to NOT NULL
)
```

**Update**
After updating the versions and adding nuget package `System.Data.SqlClient` the stack trace changed somewhat to:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException
>
> HResult=0x80131931
>
> Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>
> Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()`
>
> at `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Guid()`
>
> at `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()`
>
> at `System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)`
>
> at `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)`
>
> at `System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)`
>
> at `cbs.classifications.dal.Views.FindCodeListById(Guid id)` in ...
>
> at `cbs.classifications.services.CodeListService.GetCodeList(Guid id)` in ...
>
> at `cbs.classifications.api.Controllers.CodeListController.Get(Guid id)` in
>
> at `Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)`
>
> at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)`
>
> at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()`

**Updated** CodeLists class

```
public partial class CodeLists
{
    public CodeLists()
    {
        Levels = new HashSet<Levels>();
        Nodes = new HashSet<Nodes>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ClassificationId { get; set; }
    public Guid? DescriptionId { get; set; }
    public Guid NameId { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }

    public Classifications Classification { get; set; }
    public Translations Description { get; set; }
    public Translations Name { get; set; }
    public Users Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Levels> Levels { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Nodes> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please include `CodeLists` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the class

Comment: I know you said you checked this, but are you absolutely sure every row has an I'd?

Comment: @Crowcoder All description id's and name id's are filled, classification and owner id are NULL, but they are allow to be null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core: \`SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.\` How to troubleshoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to mark all nullable `CodeLists` properties with Nullable data types like below:

```
public class CodeLists
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClassificationId { get; set; }
    public Guid? DescriptionId { get; set; }

    public Guid NameId { get; set; }
    public Guid? OwnerId { get; set; }

}
```

`ClassificationId` and `OwnerId` are not nullable in your `CodeLists` class implementation but is nullable in the Db

Comment: This is especially important to remember when you're adding a new primitive property to an existing entity. We recently added a foreign key on an existing entity to a new table and forgot to assign values to this new column on old data. Querying this data where the foreign key was still null triggered this error. Took us a while to figure out this int was not nullable and was causing this error.

Answer (score 10):

My problem was that I had the `Nullable` feature enabled in my Class library project. Removing the `Nullable` node fixed it. EFCore was no longer throwing an error and the warnings disappeared from my models.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: No worries Raju. I think .NET 6 class libraries have this enabled by default!

Comment: No, I have enabled it.

Comment: this fixed my problem as well!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing `Nullable` feature, you can also change it to warnings only. This will stop errors from EF Core and allow you use nullability in your project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>warnings</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```