# Entity Framework Core throws SqlNullValueException when loading entities from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0

I have this MyEntity table in the database:

[image: MyEntity table in database]

The data inside MyEntity is the following:

[image: Data in MyEntity table]

The EF Core entity is the following:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting an exception:

> `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'`

when trying to load the `MyEntity` from the `DbContext`:

```
var myEntities = dbContext.Set<MyEntity>.ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the `MyInt` in your `MyEntity` database table is `nullable`, and one of the rows you are trying to load has a `MyInt` set to `null`.

To fix this, just change the type of your `MyInt` property in your entity to `Nullable<int>` or `int?`:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? MyInt { get; set; }
}
```