# Retrieve and populate data ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, data-retrieval

I have the following code in my controller where I am returning an account view passing a parameter to it as you will see below

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Account()
    {

        var findUser = await UserMgr.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

        var contactDetails =
          (from c in _context.UserPersonalDetails
           where c.ID == findUser.Id
           select c);

        var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[UserPersonalDetails] where ID={0}", findUser.Id);

        ViewBag.Data = contactDetails;

        return View(contactDetails);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public class UserPersonalDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }}
```

And this is my View where I have the model declared and

```
@model FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails

                                <form method="post" asp-action="account" asp-controller="account" id="registrationForm">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="LastName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="Phone" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <br>

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success small" id="saveUpdatedDetails" disabled><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="enableUpdate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

When the view is returned I get the following error which I tried to refactor the code several ways and yet it remains there

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails'.
```

My main question is how would I use the retrieved data to be populated in the input fields?
I appreciate any guidance/help.

Answer (score 1):

the query returns `iQueryable<UserPersonalDetails>`
where your model waiting `UserPersonalDetails`
try this edit in controller

`var contactDetails =(from c in _context.UserPersonalDetails where c.ID == findUser.Id select c).FirstOrDefault()`;

Comment: I changed it as you suggested but I am getting this error now:
SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
I have data in my table

Answer (score 1):

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

It seems that the table columns has `NULL` values, while all your properties are set with `[Required]` attribute, so, it throws this error. You can check the record in `UserPersonalDetails` table which ID equals `findUser.Id` to find if it has a null value in its columns.

A similar question was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015584/entity-framework-core-throws-system-data-sqltypes-sqlnullvalueexception-when-loa). You can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var contactDetails =
          (from c in _context.UserPersonalDetails
           where c.ID == findUser.Id
           select c);
```

To

```
if( findUser ==null) return NotFound("user is not found");

var contactDetails =
          (from c in _context.UserPersonalDetails
           where c.ID == findUser.Id
           select c).FirstOrDefault();
or even shorter:
var contactDetails = await _context.DbSet<UserPersonalDetails>()
           .Where(c=> c.ID == findUser.Id)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
And add  attribut  [Table("UserPersonalDetails")] to the top of the class.

Just remember for the future: NEVER GIVE PLURAL NAMES ENDING AT S TO ENTITY. It is very confusing since EF usually almost automaticly assingns plural names to the collections.
```

Comment: Hi Serge, that was mainly to see if I would be able to pass anything to the View class
Tried your answer bu I get an error: SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Comment: If returns a value...it does not like the FirstOrDefault() added to the end of the Linq query.
Once I removed that, it was returned results then again it fails when returning the view with this error: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails'.

Comment: I only just noticed that you are using async. I added async variant. Check my answer.

Comment: Tried to implement that and this is the new error

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__21`1[FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FriendShipping.Models.UserPersonalDetails'.

Comment: It means too many tasks runnig.  Try to assign findUserId = ... directly and remove  UserMgr.FindByNameAsync. Also remove for now var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[UserPersonalDetails] where ID={0}", findUser.Id);
        ViewBag.Data = contactDetails;   but I am not sure that it will be enough.

Comment: Tried that again no success
 var contactDetails = 
                (from c in _context.UserPersonalDetails
                 where c.ID == userID
                 select c);
Somehow my linq query contactDetails is null but my table has the userID I am looking for
Is there any other way of retrieving the contacts of a given ID without using a linq query?

Comment: Why you didn't try var contactDetails = await _context.UserPersonalDetails
           .Where(c=> c.ID == findUser.Id)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); ?

Comment: Or maybe then var contactDetails = await _context.DbSet<UserPersonalDetails>().Where(c=> c.ID == findUser.Id) .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: Changed to this now 
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Account()
        {
            var findUser = await UserMgr.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

            var contactDetails = await _context.UserPersonalDetails.Where(c => c.ID == findUser.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return View(contactDetails);
        } 
it returns SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Comment: The funny thing is that the findUser.Id has value - it is not null at all

Comment: Pls check my last update in my answer. Use var contactDetails = await _context.DbSet<UserPersonalDetails>()
           .Where(c=> c.ID == findUser.Id)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: Thank you, I will try what you mentioned :)

Comment: It seems like the issue is that the query does not like the fact that some of the results are null. For example Phone is null and I set to allow null values

Comment: Did you try var contactDetails = await _context.DbSet<UserPersonalDetails>() .Where(c=> c.ID == findUser.Id) .FirstOrDefaultAsync() and what error you have after this.

Comment: I get this error - SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. Plus it does not like having DbSet, had to change it to Set. 
I have null values in the table as I allow them to be nullable.

Comment: Have you added ()  to Set?