# Disable [Required] attribute base on condition in ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a table `UserApplication` which has more than 100 columns. The model class for it looks like this:

```
public class UserApplication
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    .....  
    // so on ....
}
```

I have break these column data section-wise into multiple pages (razor pages asp.net core 3.1). So roughly I have 10 pages, each having 10 column values respectively, some has required attribute

Now on page load I get an error

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

This error occurs because of null values for required columns (on another pages).

Is there any way I can disable the `[Required]` attribute on page load? And later enable it when user post the page and show required validation message.

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the example where  you the exception, pls?

Comment: @Sergey: Error screenshot added

Comment: Sorry but I still can't see where the exeption was trown originaly. Can you show where the exception was trown at the first place pls?

Comment: Actually the exception is from database, so there is discrepancy between the requiredness of some property and corresponding table column - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo/55889874#55889874

Comment: @IvanStoev :  Removing required attribute will solve this issue, but then on post request validation also stopped working. Any way to handle both ?

Comment: If you have 10 pages of data - you'd have to have 10 model classes, each representing a single page of data - in that case, you can set the `[Required]` annotations for this particular page and have validation work, too.

Comment: @marc_s: If i used 10 model classes, then 10 different tables get generated in database. Here in my case this is single table where user dump data (just to dump user input, its a big form entry, so for better UI, i break it into multiple pages), and later based on some logic respective data gets validated and stored in another table (multiple tables).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also get this error when you have not built and run your update scripts on the database, so your DB doesn't actually have the columns it needs.

Just to double check, have you created the migrations for these columns, and applied them to your Database?

Comment: Database is already created, data insertion done, now when I came for validation part am facing this issue. Removing required will fix issue, but then validation will stopped working, Any other approach to achieve both

Comment: Its odd you are getting this error on a Read operation, I would expect to see an error like this when attempting to insert a new row of data into the DB, not when performing `.find`, did you already have rows in this table before the migration and didn't have default values on the required fields, potentially resulting in creating rows with invalid data?

Though... I am fairly sure that if you try to do that, EF Core fails the migration and complains that it needs a default value, if I recall correctly.