# EF generate System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I would like to ask you what is wrong in this query.

```
    public async Task<RecipeHeader> GetRecipeWithRecipeLineChild(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return await dbSet.Where(x => x.RecipeHeaderId == id)
                    .Include(x => x.RecipeLines)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Unit)
                    .Include(x => x.CalculationMethod)
                    .ThenInclude(y => y.Calculation)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Repo} GetRecipeWithRecipeLineChild function error", typeof(RecipeHeaderRepository));
                return new RecipeHeader();
            }
        }
```

when I use `.QueryString()` and copy to AzureDataStudio it works.

but in my app generate

> 2022-05-19 13:38:39.3178|10100|ERROR|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'RecipesApi.Data.AppDbContext'.
> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
> at lambda_method334(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. at lambda_method334(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator ) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

Here is Db model

```
    [Index(nameof(RecipeId),IsUnique =true)]
    public class RecipeHeader
    {
        
        [Key]
        public int RecipeHeaderId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string RecipeId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string RecipeName { get; set; } = "";
        public int? CalculationMethodId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CalculationMethodId")]
        public virtual CalculationMethod CalculationMethod  { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public int? PrescriptionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PrescriptionId")]
        public virtual Prescription Prescription { get; set; }
        public bool ColorRecipe { get; set; }
        public byte? Salt { get; set; }
        public byte? Program { get; set; }
        public ushort Version { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; } = "system";
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public byte RecipeStatus { get; set; }= 1;
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
    }
```

Firstly I assume there is some error in my ViewModel and AutoMapper. So I skip viewModel Automapper etc and use DB model but have same result...
Now I'm little bit lost I think it will be some small stupid mistake but I cannot see it...
Also here printscreen of my dbTable schema[image: Db Table Schema]

Comment: Sorry my mistake fixed

Comment: Something wrong with your model. EF Core expects not null field, but retrieved NULL.

Comment: You aren't using AutoMapper anywhere in your query. The error complains about the results, not the query. In EF Core 5 and later, an error is thrown if a `null` value is returned for a non-nullable property, even if it's a reference type. For example, if `RecipeName` is null, you'll get an error because the type is `string`, not `string?`

Comment: To ensure you don't get such errors the nullability of the properties should map the table fields. That's annoying, because you won't get any compilation or runtime errors until a `null` is encountered.

Comment: BTW both the `RecipeName` and `Comment` fields are nullable but the properties are `string` instead of `string?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core: \`SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.\` How to troubleshoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo)

Answer (score 15):

I fix it when I comment out    `<!-- <Nullable>enable</Nullable> -->`
from .csproj

Comment: Had similar issue migrating from 5.0 to 6.0 and setting nullable to disable fixed it.  Commenting out does the same thing like @LukasVanek commented.

Comment: Had this issue when migrate from 3.1 to 6.0 too! and this fixed the issue!!

Comment: I had the same issue when taking out ApplicationDbContext from the Asp.net core project to a separate class library. This solution saves my day..!!.

Comment: Over here, there are zero mis-matches b/t the nullability ("[Required]") of EF POCO model members and their respective database fields.  So the fact that this beautiful little fix quashed our "SqlNullValueException" worries me a little.  Why did .NET 5/6/7 introduce this problem in the 1st place? What else did I lose (read: "break") by dropping "<Nullable>enable..."?  Do I need to do the same in EVERY dependent .csproj?  ...even if that Project doesn't reference EF or the POCOs?

Comment: why this works ? 

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was not that the entity and sql column mismatched in terms of nullability, as they did match, both were nullable. The problem was that the given property had a `[Required]` attribute on it. Removing that attribute fixed the problem. While it's true that it didn't make sense to mark a nullable property like this Required, nonetheless this was in a migration from legacy Entity Framework, which didn't mind the issue.

Entity:

```
[Required] // <-- problem! EFCore needs this removed
public DateTime? GracePeriodExpires { get; set; }
```

SQL:

```
[GracePeriodExpires] DATETIME2 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue by making column as notnull

and updated all the columns which null in database

after that it worked for me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, and I think the OP, the issue was what Panagiotis Kanavos mentions in the comments.

It was due to a nullable field I was returning was being mapped to a non nullable field.

When the data returns a null value then you get the runtime error. The error message doesn't specify which field is causing the error.

Changing the offending field in my code from `DateTime` type to `DateTime?` to match the nullable field in the db schema resolved it for me.