# Entity Framework Core 6 - System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using EF Core 6 on .NET 6.0 and am looking at this error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

The error message should indicate that EF Core is trying to read a value for a required property, i.e. a property which should never have null value in the database, but instead the underlying data reader reports null value for that property in some record(s).

[Entity Framework Core: `SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.` How to troubleshoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo)

Disabling `nullable reference type` the error disappears and everything works well.

Is it possible to investigate exactly what field is causing this issue, debugging the code doesn't give me more details.

Is there some technique to get the name of the offending field or fields?

Visually I didn't find any discrepancy between the database and the model

Answer (score 1):

Check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) related with Nullable reference types

> In a nullable aware context:
>
> A variable of a reference type T must be initialized with non-null,
> and may never be assigned a value that may be null.
>
> A variable of areference type T? may be initialized with null or
> assigned null, but is required to be checked against null before
> de-referencing.

assuming an entity:

```
public class SomeEntity   
{   
    [Key]     
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Prop { get; set; }    
}
```

If you enabled nullable reference type, Name and Prop property would never be assigned with null

Assuming the Db:

[image]
[image]

When you read data from db and assign the null value in db to your entity,you would get the error you've shown

> Is it possible to investigate exactly what field is causing this issue

All properties  type of T instead of T? in your entity with the column could be null in db would cause this issue

Both Disabling nullable reference type and Setting your property which may have null value in db with T? would  solve the issue.

For example,in my case,the Name column and Prop column could be null in db,when you check your entity, Name  and Prop property should be type of string? instead of string .

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is the cause.
But my question (maybe is not so clear, it's my falut) is about how to get some sort of notification from the debbugger, the call stack, or from a verbose output, an indicatin of what field has null value

It's not so easy to verify manually because my entity are a customization of a the aspnet identity database

E.G: calling  `_userManager.FindByNameAsync` i got this error

Apparently i've filled all nullable values but maybe the error is caused by other related entity e.g `Roles`, `Claims`, and so on

So i'd like to get a clear indication about what is the first field(if there are more) that has caused the problem.

If possible of course!

Comment: Not the answer to your question,but  may help,you could try with  interceptors  to check which command got wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors