# Getting System.DBNull Error when using WHERE

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

```
var dbUser = dbContext.Users
    .Where(c => c.userId == ulong.Parse(userId))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm using this code trying to retrieve a user but all I get is
`System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."`

userId is a non nullable ulong.

Comment: It could be that you have a non-nullable property in your User object (code-wise) but there are nulls in the data (database-wise).

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? I'm not aware of any system that supports unsigned 64-bit integers (besides MySQL, but we don't talk about MySQL...) which why I'm curious why you're using `UInt64` (aka `ulong`) here...

Comment: @topsail I already checked and there are no nullable values in the database

Comment: @Dai I'm using mysql, should have clarified that

Comment: @JoshuaSarlette I recommend you stick to using `Int32` (aka `int`). I know that MySQL's `unsigned` types do look attractive, but unfortunately they aren't supported by any of the other leading RDBMS, so if you want your application to be portable (and future-proof) then I recommend avoiding unsigned integer types. (I mention "future proofing" because my observation is that [MySQL is falling far behind](https://www.theregister.com/2021/12/06/mysql_a_pretty_poor_database/) Postgres, and we skate to where the puck is headed, y'know...)

Comment: @Dai The values stored in that row are to big for int32, so I would need to change it to string. That isn't the point tho, why does it give me this error. It doesn't make any sense because how would it think it's a dbnull if it's an ulong.

Comment: @JoshuaSarlette How on earth did you end up with `UserId` values exceeding 2 billion?

Comment: @JoshuaSarlette Anyway, the error is because of your `ulong.Parse` call which is incorrectly placed _inside_ a Linq expression. Move the `ulong.Parse` call to a `ulong parsedUserId = ulong.Parse( userId );` line _above_ your query, then use only `parsedUserId` in your query.

Comment: _Also_, the runtime value of your `userId` local appears to be `null` (I am not referring to your `userid unsigned integer NOT NULL` column). It also helps to not give locals the _exact_ same name as columns because it confuses everybody: your EF entity class properties should be using `PascalCase` not `camelCase`.

Comment: @Dai it's exceeding 2 billions because those Ids are provided extarnelly by Discord, which for some reason exceed 2 billions.

Comment: @JoshuaSarlette Ah, okay - that's a valid excuse, actually. [Apparently Discord calls them "snowflakes"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes) - but in that case, I'd recommend you rename the column to `DiscordUserId`.

Comment: @Dai unfortunately moving the parse outside the code and making sure it's not null didn't fix it.

Comment: In which case the problem is not diagnosable from the information you've provided.

Comment: @Dia what other informations would be required to solve this?

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statements, your full EF `DbContext` and `class User` definitions (including where-and-how you configure EF, either with `[Attributes]` or `ModelBuilder`), as well as a raw trace of the _actual_ SQL that EF is generating - and the source-code to the entire method where you're using this Linq method (and any instance state passed-in via `this`).

Comment: Forget about `Where`, you should be getting the same error if you simply do `context.Users.ToList()`. Look at the *other* properties of `User` class, and more specifically of type `string`. Some of them is marked as `[Required]` (or you have NRT enabled and type is `string` instead of `string?`) while in database it is not and there are records with `NULL` value in it. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo/55889874#55889874