# Why am I seeing "Data is Null" on query in EF Core 6 on a new build?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building a new application using EF Core 6. I have a table, tblAttendance

```
public partial class tblAttendance
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LogoutTime { get; set; }
    public string? ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string? LogonServer { get; set; }
}
```

When I make Select All queryies

```
var attendanceData = dbContext.tblAttendances
                .Select(a => new AttendanceData
                {
                    UserName = a.UserName ?? "",
                    LoginDate = a.LoginDate,
                    LoginTime = a.LoginTime,
                    LogoutDate = a.LogoutDate,
                    LogoutTime = a.LogoutTime,
                    ComputerName = a.ComputerName ?? "",
                    LogonServer = a.LogonServer ?? ""
                });
```

the query returns correct results.

But when I try to filter the data I receive a "Data is Null" error.

I have modified my code to use a simple FromSqlRaw statement

```
string query = @$"Select * from tblAttendance ";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                if (query.IndexOf("where") < 0) query += "where ";
                query +=$"UserName = '{userName}' ";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(computerName))
            {
                if (query.IndexOf("where") < 0) query += "where "; else query += "AND ";
                query += $"ComputerName = '{computerName}' ";
            }
            if (loginDate.Ticks>0)
            {
                var year=loginDate.Year; var month=loginDate.Month;
                if (query.IndexOf("where") < 0) query += "where "; else query += "AND ";
                query += $" DATEPART(year, loginDate) = {year} and DATEPART(month, loginDate) = {month}";
            }
            var results=dbContext.tblAttendances.FromSqlRaw(query).ToList();
```

which also gives the Data is Null error, although when run through server explorer it returns correct results.

My data context builder for this table is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblAttendance>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id).HasName("PK_tblAttendanceScript");

            entity.ToTable("tblAttendance");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.UserName, e.LoginDate }, "UserNames_tblAttendanceScript");

            entity.Property(e => e.ComputerName).HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(e => e.LoginDate).HasColumnType("date");
            entity.Property(e => e.LogonServer).HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(e => e.LogoutDate).HasColumnType("date");
            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(50);
        });
```

Being new to EF (and Core) I am uncertain now where to even look.  A general (admittedly brief) search online has revealed nothing that I can apply.

******************** Edit adding sample data ***************************
Here is a sample of the results I receive from the database running the query directly:

```
749405  aanderso    2023-06-29  08:58:48.0000000    2023-06-29  16:05:17.0000000    MCA-TS24VM  192.168.100.90
749423  aanderso    2023-06-29  15:00:20.0000000    2023-06-29  16:05:17.0000000    MCA-TS25VM  192.168.100.97
762067  aanderso    2023-06-29  08:58:48.0000000    2023-06-29  16:05:17.0000000    MCA-TS24VM  192.168.100.90
724075  abala   2023-06-01  07:34:42.0000000    2023-06-01  NULL    MCA-TS22VM  192.168.100.79
734462  abala   2023-06-01  07:34:42.0000000    2023-06-01  18:23:26.0000000    MCA-TS22VM  192.168.100.79
747249  abala   2023-06-01  07:34:42.0000000    2023-06-01  18:23:26.0000000    MCA-TS22VM  192.168.100.79
759911  abala   2023-06-01  07:34:42.0000000    2023-06-01  18:23:26.0000000    MCA-TS22VM  192.168.100.79
```

The query being used is `Select * from tblAttendance  where DATEPART(year, loginDate) = 2023 and DATEPART(month, loginDate) = 6`

Comment: I tested your code(your code is okay),please add example data and expected data to test

Comment: Can you share full error? meanwhile you can check other threads - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo

Comment: Based on your scenario and description, it seems that while you are building dynamic query, may be something doesn't build  according to the correct syntax, please double check your final `query string` and paste it within your database management studio, it will help you to point the exact area of trouble. Because, your overall code seems correct, so dynamic query might have the issue.

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi Added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the EF table model definition

```
public partial class tblAttendance
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LogoutTime { get; set; }
    public string? ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string? LogonServer { get; set; }
}
```

LogoutTime `public TimeSpan LogoutTime { get; set; }` is defined as required (no '?').  This is telling EF that there cannot be a Null value.  In the database, however, it is possible to have a Null logout time. This is what was breaking the query.  Modified this to `public TimeSpan? LogoutTime { get; set; }` and everything worked as it was designed to.