# AWS Lambda function using Annotation Framework with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

Using Visual Studio 2022, lambda annotation template and trying to use EF (against a MySQL database).

I have done a `services.AddDBContext<myContext>` in startup preceded by `services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql();`.

I pick up the `DbContext` from the functions constructor just like `calculatorService` is picked up.

```
private MyContext _myContext;
private ICalculatorService _calculatorService;

 public Functions(ICalculatorService calculatorService, MyContext myContext)
 { 
     _calculatorService = calculatorService;
     _myContext = myContext;
 }
```

I have this code in a function

```
[LambdaFunction()]
[HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Post, "/Subscriptions")]
public Task PostSub()
{
    var thisone = _myContext.Databasedetails.ToList();
```

It fails  in the executable line above with this error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Have I got the DI set up incorrectly?

Comment: Nothing to do with Lambda. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55883704/4800344

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core: \`SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.\` How to troubleshoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883704/entity-framework-core-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-how-to-troubleshoo)

Comment: Looks like that was the issue.  Thanks

Comment: No worries, enjoy using AWS :)