# Entity Framework/Entity Framework Core Generator -The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889874/8372325 relates to my issue. My issue differs as my project is a database first design and I am using Entity Framework Core Generator to generate by .NET classes.

I am working with Entity Framework for a project I am working, and I get the following error:

> An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'EventTracking.EventNotes'. The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null.

I traced it and realized that it comes from the fact "EventNotes" is nullable in the database but the generated C# class has it marked as "string", so when my query executes it throws this exception.

I have found 2 possible solutions

1. Change the field from "string" to "string?"
2. Or add a `DefaultIfEmpty()` to my query before returning the value.

The issues that I have with the 2 solutions so far are

1. I generated all my models using Entity Framework Generator, and as far as I could tell I couldn't find a way to specify it in the generation.yml file. I wouldn't want to go in manually to change all string -> string? and I don't want it overwritten
2. I don't want to have to append DefaultIfEmpty() before every single query call.

I was hoping I could find a solution where I can either alter my `generation.yml` file so that I can specify it to generate "string?" instead of "string" for NULL varchar, or if there is a setting I can override in the `DbContext` class so that I am able to map the null varchar to a string.

My code calls the entity with

```
return await _context.EventTrackings.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventTracking]
(
    [EventTrackingId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [EventTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [DateKey] INT NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [EventDurationMinutes] INT NULL,
    [EventStatus] VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
    [EventNotes] VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
    [CreatedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(), 
    [CreatedByUserId] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY ([CreatedByUserId]) REFERENCES ElkUser([ElkUserId]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([EventTypeId]) REFERENCES EventType([EventTypeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EventTrackingId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventTrackingId] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
)
```

Generated C# class from Entity Framework Generator

```
public partial class EventTracking
{
    public EventTracking()
    {
        Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    }

    public int EventTrackingId { get; set; }
    public int EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public int DateKey { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    public int? EventDurationMinutes { get; set; }

    public string EventStatus { get; set; }
    public string EventNotes { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ElkUser CreatedByUserElkUser { get; set; }
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

The generated Map file specifying that the field is **not** required

```
builder.Property(t => t.EventStatus)
            .HasColumnName("EventStatus")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255);

builder.Property(t => t.EventNotes)
            .HasColumnName("EventNotes")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255);
```

Versions in use:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` - v7.0.15
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` - v7.0.15
- CLI `EntityFrameworkCoreGenerator` - 6.0.1

Comment: Reminder that EF Core has its own [scaffolding command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for db-first use cases

Comment: Anyways, according to these [docs](https://efg.loresoft.com/configuration/) you can specify `nullable: true`

Comment: @MateusZampol You mind submitting this as an actual answer, the nullable: true did exactly what I was hoping to do, alter the generation. I didn't know EF Core had its own scaffolding command so that is nice to know for the future! I assumed I had nullable support enabled by default since the "INT NULL" generated as "int?", I looked in the section for "data" in my generation.yml as that is where I thought it would be, didn't think to look at the project level where I had ```nullable: false```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is the use of the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` setting in the project file (.csproj). This setting enables the nullable reference types introduced with the release of C# 8, which requires the use of the symbol '?' to indicate nullable types.

By default, strings are nullable in C#, so you can turn off the C# 8 feature that treats them as non-nullable. To do this, change the setting within your project's file to `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` (I haven't tried this myself, though).

Alternatively, you can explicitly declare the types of your properties as nullable using the '?' syntax, as shown below:

```
builder.Property<string?>(t => t.EventStatus)
            .HasColumnName("EventStatus")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255);

builder.Property<string?>(t => t.EventNotes)
            .HasColumnName("EventNotes")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255);
```

Comment: Thank you for the two options! The first one which is disable nullable in my csproj worked great, this is a project using the latest version and I guess my legacy code never had this option so I didn't know it existed. If I the Entity Framework Generator didn't have the setting I was looking for, I would've gone with this route and disabled it for my whole project. The second option would've worked but it falls under my point #2 where it would be overwritten each time I regenerated the entity framework models!