# Asp.net - Core - Statement not setting the Dto's of the navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I wanted to use a repository option that first retrieves all records but also the includes as well and then select one client based on a given Id using a where clause. I also wanted to include all the notes for this entity.. Client.. as well as its address and Jobs via the includes however if I do try and project the `Address` to an `AddressDto` and a collection of `ClientNotes` to a list of `ClientNotesDto`  it errors with

> "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null
>   values."

OK so here is the client entity where the clients are loaded from...

```
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES
{
#nullable enable
    public class Client : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
    {
        public Client()
        {
            ClientNotes = new List<Note>();
            Jobs = new List<Job>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientNo { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool Company { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Abn { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool IsWarrantyCompany { set; get; }
        public bool RequiresPartsPayment { set; get; }
        public string ClientFirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ClientLastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Phone { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Address1 { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Address2 { get; set; } = null!;
        public string BankName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string BankBSB { get; set; } = null!;
        public string BankAccount { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDeActivated { get; set; }
        public bool Activity { get; set; }

        // One warranty company client to a job.
        public int? WarrantyCompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Job WarrantyCompany { get; set; } = null!;

        // One suburb to a client.
        public int? SuburbId { get; set; }
        public virtual Suburb Suburb { get; set; } = null!;

        // If its a warranty company then we simply link it one to one to the brand id.
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; } = null!;

        // Multiple notes for each client.
        public virtual ICollection<Note> ClientNotes { get; }

        // Multiple jobs for each client.
        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Job> WarrantyCompanyJobs { get; } = default!;
    }
#nullable disable
}
```

Here is the clientDto..

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Job;
using JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Address;
using JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Notes;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client
{
    public class ClientDetailsDto
    {

        public ClientDetailsDto()
        {
            Address = new AddressDto();
            //ClientNotes = new List<ClientNoteDto>();
            //ClientJobs = new List<ClientJobDto>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientNo { get; set; }
        public bool Company { get; set; }
        public bool IsWarrantyCompany { set; get; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ClientLastName { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string DeActivated { get; set; }
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public int SuburbId { get; set; }
        public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ClientJobDto> ClientJobs { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<ClientNoteDto> ClientNotes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Yes there are a few properties but its fairly simple.

The repository is using this method to obtain all clients before doing the "Where" clause to get a single client..

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Now bear in mind I get the actual client and its actually projected to the DTO. However If I set project just to the `ClientDto` it works.. I get data back for a single client.

If uncomment the Address and `ClientNotes` projections it fails with an the above error.

I was under the impression that with includes I should actually get the associated or related entities and I am not. Is it because of lazy loaded etc..

Here is the statement:

```
var result = ClientDATARepository?.AllIncluding(c => c.Jobs, c => c.ClientNotes, c => c.Suburb).Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(fetchedClient =>
            new ClientDetailsDto {
                Id = fetchedClient.Id,
                ClientNo = fetchedClient.ClientNo,
                Company = fetchedClient.Company,
                IsWarrantyCompany = fetchedClient.IsWarrantyCompany,
                CompanyName = fetchedClient.CompanyName,
                ClientFirstName = fetchedClient.ClientFirstName,
                ClientLastName = fetchedClient.ClientLastName,
                MobilePhone = fetchedClient.MobilePhone,
                DeActivated = fetchedClient.DateDeActivated.HasValue ? "true" : "false",
                CreatedOn = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClient, "CreatedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                ModifiedOn = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClient, "ModifiedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),

                Address =    // ..I believe it fails here.
                    new AddressDto {
                        Address1 = fetchedClient.Address1,
                        Address2 = fetchedClient.Address2,
                        SuburbId = fetchedClient.Suburb.Id,
                        SuburbName = fetchedClient.Suburb.SuburbName,
                        StateShortName = fetchedClient.Suburb.State.StateShortName,
                        Postcode = fetchedClient.Suburb.PostCode,
                    },

                ClientNotes = fetchedClient.ClientNotes.Select(fetchedClientNote =>  // ..and here..
                    new ClientNoteDto {
                        id = fetchedClientNote.Id,
                        Details = fetchedClientNote.Details,
                        NoteType = NoteTypeDATARepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == fetchedClientNote.NoteTypeId).Name,
                        CreatedOnDate = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClientNote, "CreatedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                        CreatedOnTime = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClientNote, "CreatedOn").ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),

                        ModifiedOnDate = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClientNote, "ModifiedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                        ModifiedOnTime = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClientNote, "ModifiedOn").ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),    
                });
```

As I mentioned when I try and load `Address` and `ClientNotes` its throwing the above error saying data cannot be null..

I'd like to know why I cant load `Address` and `ClientNotes` and more importantly how to make it so I do load these.. Further.. why cant I do this and still have it as an IQueryable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719683/data-is-null-this-method-or-property-cannot-be-called-on-null-values)

Comment: what does your debug window sshow ? Does it show that clientNotes and Address are filled if you do a quick watch on them ?